# how to add encrypted connection string in web.config to my DBContext mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

I have UsersContext as dbcontext in mvc 4 project. I have **Encrypted Connection String in Web.config** because site is in *Shared Server*. My DbContext is :

```
Public Class UsersContext
    Inherits DbContext
      Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("DefaultConnection")
      End Sub

    Public Property UserProfiles As DbSet(Of UserProfile)
End Class
```

The 'DefaultConnection' is Encrypted in web.config. 

How can i use my Decrypt Function and initialize conntection.

```
   'I want to do Something like this : 

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New(MyStringDecrpytor(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString))
  End Sub
```

Where  MyStringDecrpytor is function which decrypt the connection string to the original text.

Comment: where is your code for encription?

Comment: its public shared function and decrypt the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rely on the base `DbContext`, you can set the connecting sting programmatically in your derived constructor. Just set `DbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` to whatever you want. In VB.NET I believe it would be:

```
Public Sub New()
  MyBase.New()
  My.Database.Connection.ConnectingString = DecryptFunction("encryptedstringhere")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use the Aspnet_regiis.exe tool to encrypt the sections.  It is not necessary to provide your own encryption or decryption logic.  See the official [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx).

> You can use the ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe) to encrypt or decrypt sections of a Web configuration file. ASP.NET will automatically decrypt encrypted configuration elements when the Web.config file is processed.